# How To Make Pie Graph become case insensitive

Tags: google-sheets, pie-chart

I am adding pie charts into a Google Sheets page, but they are just messy.

This is because the data it is pulling from has (distinct) but minor differences between each other. To put it more easily:

- `Roofer` and `roofer` are showing as 2 separate slices in the chart.

I want the processing to be case-insensitive, considering `Roofer` and `roofer` as the same category.

Can this be done in Google Sheets? How about excel?

Same data and sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YlNXVs6yljh339b84YVsjiMSaYxt76n13bWGbuM-iBk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Best to show some sample data and a chart in a test sheet. ie make a test sheet and include the link. Then someone will show you.

Comment: @bcperth added, please see above

Comment: Ok thanks. I will take a look later today. There are several ways to sort this out - none too difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only easy way I see to do this is to insert helper columns to clean the data. Then graph the clean data.

Using this technique produces this result - based on graphing colC.

[image: Chart Based on clean data in Col C]

The formula in cell B2 - to remove spaces - is:

```
=arrayformula(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A20, " ", "")))
```

The formula in cell C2 - to convert case - is:

```
=iferror(arrayformula(upper(left(B2:B20, 1)) & lower(right(B2:B20, len(B2:B20)-1))),"")
```

The data range on the chart is C1:C1000

You can hide Cols A and B for display purposes.
Alternatively move the helper columns to out of view columns.

The idea with this is you type the raw data into col A as shown, and the clean data appears in ColC.

Comment: OK please let me know if this meets your need. It is possible to do all this in a script, and then overwrite ColA, so you don't need helper columns. But this is easier to understand.

Comment: I will try to implement this later today and circle back around with the resullts

Comment: I did not need to remove the spaces, they were intentional, the second formula worked well. thanks!